# Is there any performance impact if I set timeout value to 0 in node server?

Tags: node.js, nodes

I am facing the problem of automatic connection lost after a few minutes of inactivity in browser which causes major  problem to run my program. When I query on internet then I found that A value of 0 will disable the timeout behavior on incoming connections. But I am little bit confused here, is there any performance impact if value is set to 0?

Comment: Connection to what? How is that connection made? A value of 0 to what?

Comment: @Nik Kyriakides , connection to node server, and 0 is value of timeout in node which is used for making session alive